# Disable screen orientation in Android Studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-activity, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I want to turn off auto rotation in my app, I know you can do it per activity in Manifest by typing `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

But I have a lot of activities, is there anyway to set it for the whole app at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this for all of your activities making an PortraitActivity that all your activities extends.

```
public abstract class PortraitActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```